# PHP: array_pop returns the empty string

Tags: php, explode, fqdn

I'm using explode to break a FQDN and store it in an array. Calling pop on that array however returns a blank or empty string, and I can't figure out why.

```
 $domains = explode(".",str_replace("example.com","","test.example.com"));
 print "Test: " . $domains[0] . "<br>";
 $target = array_pop($domains);
 print "Target: " . $target . "<br>";
```

Running the above code results in:

```
 Test: test
 Target:
```

Why doesn't $target contain "test"?

Comment: Didn't checked that as you.. But, now its clear, try `var_dump($domains)` to see.. It contains **`2`** elements.. `test` and an empty string. However, this is not a reason for a downvote (imo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In effect, here's what you're actually doing:

```
var_dump(explode('.', 'test.'));

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

You get two elements in the array: "test" and what's after the period i.e. an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

> array_pop() pops and returns the last value of the array

Use [array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: I actually want the last element of the array, it was the whitespace as mentioned by Nev Stokes that threw me off. Thanks for the reply!